# How to not showing div area when specific checkbox button is not checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".registration_info input").click(function(){
    if($(this).prop("checked")){
      $(".registration_info input:checkbox").prop("checked", false);
      $(this).prop("checked", true);
    }
  });
});

// -------- dealer area --------

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#area").click(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
      $("#some_area").show();
    }
    else
      $("#some_area").hide();
  });
});
```

```css
#some_area {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                                                              
<div class="registration_info">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Item1">Item1
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Item2" id="area">Item2
  </label>
  <label>
  <input type="checkbox" value="Item3">Item3
  </label>
  
  <div>
    <div id="some_area">Some_area
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, I have three checkbox and only can have one checked at the moment.
Also, there is a gray color area will show out when "Item2" was checked.

When I check item2 first (the gray area show) then check item1 or item3, the item2 will un-check but the gray color area still show out.

How to not show gray area when item2 is not checked?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use jquery [**toggle**](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) when user click another checkbox. You can sum it up to this:

```js
$(".registration_info input").click(function() {
  if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
    $(".registration_info input:checkbox").prop("checked", false);
    $(this).prop("checked", true);
  }
  //here toggle #some_area element according to check status
  $("#some_area").toggle($("#area").prop("checked"));
});
```

```css
#some_area {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="registration_info">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Item1" />Item1</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Item2" id="area" />Item2</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Item3" />Item3</label>
  <div>
    <div id="some_area">Some_area</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

p.s. By the way why you don't use radio buttons instead?

Comment: @LateBloomer Glad that I helped you.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done **within the .registration_info click event**:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  $("#some_area").hide();
  
  $(".registration_info input").click(function(){
    
    $("#some_area").hide();
    
    if($(this).prop("checked")){
      $(".registration_info input:checkbox").prop("checked", false);
      $(this).prop("checked", true);
      if ($(this).attr('id')=='area'){
        $("#some_area").show();
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#some_area {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                                                              
<div class="registration_info">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Item1">Item1
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Item2" id="area">Item2
  </label>
  <label>
  <input type="checkbox" value="Item3">Item3
  </label>
  
  <div>
    <div id="some_area">Some_area
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should bind a `change` handler, not a click `handler`:

```js
$('.registration_info').on('change', function(e) {
    $(this).find('input').not(e.target).prop('checked', false);
    $('#some_area').toggle($('#area').prop('checked'));
});
```

```css
#some_area {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="registration_info">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Item1">Item1
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Item2" id="area">Item2
  </label>
  <label>
  <input type="checkbox" value="Item3">Item3
  </label>
  
  <div>
    <div id="some_area">Some_area
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first of all, you can use radio inputs for doing toggles...

Second, you are calling the click event only on "#area" so the check won't happen when you click a different element, it will happen only when you uncheck/check the "#area" element.

To work around this, you can place a class on each checkbox input and do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".some-class").click(function(){
    if($("#area").is(":checked")){
      $("#some_area").show();
    }
    else
      $("#some_area").hide();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using only 2 lines of CSS and no javascript at all. To implement this, I slightly modified your HTML to make the input a sibling of the final div you're targetting or one of its parents, allowing me to use `~` , the "general sibling" selector.

```css
#some_area {display: none;}
#area:checked ~ div #some_area  {display:block;}
```

```html
<div class="registration_info">
  <input type="checkbox" value="Item1" id="item1"><label for="item1">Item1</label>
  <input type="checkbox" value="Item2" id="area"><label for="area">Item2</label>
  <input type="checkbox" value="Item3" id="item3"><label for="item3">Item3</label>
  <div>
    <div id="some_area">Some_area</div>
  </div>
</div>
```